mutate several combinations of var prefixes and suffixes, conditionally
I want to write a shorter version of this code:
ResultsTable <- ResultsTable %>%
  mutate(V_a  = as.integer(V_a  + h2_a),
         V_b  = as.integer(V_b  + h2_b),
         V_c  = as.integer(V_c  + h2_c),
         V_d  = as.integer(V_d  + h2_d),
         V_e  = as.integer(V_e  + h2_e),
         V_f  = as.integer(V_f  + h2_f))

the point it that there are several variable prefixes and suffixes that need to be combined.
also, this should be done only for lines where ResultsTable$cond == 1, but all lines must be kept.
I tried using across(), but that doesn't seem to work with both prefixes and suffixes.
I don't even know how to approach this. help!

It is easier to help if you provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Here is a simple made up example -
df <- data.frame(cond = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0), 
                 V_a = 1:5, V_b = 11:15, 
                 h2_a = 26:30, h2_b = 36:40)

df

#  cond V_a V_b h2_a h2_b
#1    1   1  11   26   36
#2    1   2  12   27   37
#3    0   3  13   28   38
#4    1   4  14   29   39
#5    0   5  15   30   40

One way to automate this is using across and pick. For better visibility of the results I create new columns to store the output (res_V_a and res_V_b) using .names argument in across. For these results column we check if the cond column is either 1 or 0 and use ifelse to apply the condition.
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("V"), .names = "res_{col}") + pick(starts_with("h2")),
         across(starts_with("res"), ~ifelse(cond == 1, ., 
                                           get(sub("res_", "", cur_column())))))

#  cond V_a V_b h2_a h2_b res_V_a res_V_b
#1    1   1  11   26   36      27      47
#2    1   2  12   27   37      29      49
#3    0   3  13   28   38       3      13
#4    1   4  14   29   39      33      53
#5    0   5  15   30   40       5      15

and if you don't want to create new columns and modify only existing columns.
df %>%
  mutate(pick(starts_with("V")) + pick(starts_with("h2")),
         across(starts_with("V"), ~ifelse(cond == 1, ., 
                                        . - get(sub("V", "h2", cur_column())))))

#  cond V_a V_b h2_a h2_b
#1    1  27  47   26   36
#2    1  29  49   27   37
#3    0   3  13   28   38
#4    1  33  53   29   39
#5    0   5  15   30   40


thanks, i dont completely understand the double use of across, but it seems to work. How do I convert this so it replaces the values of the original variables (V_a, V_b) ?

Updated the answer to modify only the original variables. @BoTz

I prefer to do these kinds of operations in base R. You can write a helper function to do this for you:
add_cols <- function(dat, target_prefix, to_add_prefix, suffixes) {
    target_cols <- paste0(target_prefix, suffixes)
    to_add_cols <- paste0(to_add_prefix, suffixes)
    dat[target_cols] <- Map(
        \(x, y, d = dat) d[[x]] + d[[y]],
        target_cols,
        to_add_cols
    )
    dat
}

Let's create a ResultsTable like this:
ResultsTable
#   V_a V_b V_c V_d V_e h2_a h2_b h2_c h2_d h2_e
# 1   1   2   3   4   5    1    2    3    4    5
# 2   1   2   3   4   5    1    2    3    4    5

Then just apply this to the data. As you're assigning back to the original column, we expect the V_ columns to double:
add_cols(ResultsTable, "V_", "h2_", letters[1:5])
#   V_a V_b V_c V_d V_e h2_a h2_b h2_c h2_d h2_e
# 1   2   4   6   8  10    1    2    3    4    5
# 2   2   4   6   8  10    1    2    3    4    5

Modifying rows conditionally
If you only want to do this in the case of some rows, you can simply apply the function to a subset of the data and assign it only to those rows.
ResultsTable$cond <- 1:2 # create cond column

# Apply function to subset of data and apply conditionally
ResultsTable[ResultsTable$cond == 1, ] <- add_cols(
    ResultsTable[ResultsTable$cond == 1, ],
    "V_", "h2_", letters[1:5]
)
ResultsTable
#   V_a V_b V_c V_d V_e h2_a h2_b h2_c h2_d h2_e cond
# 1   2   4   6   8  10    1    2    3    4    5    1
# 2   1   2   3   4   5    1    2    3    4    5    2

Example data
ResultsTable  <- structure(list(V_a = c(1L, 1L), V_b = c(2L, 2L), V_c = c(3L, 
3L), V_d = c(4L, 4L), V_e = c(5L, 5L), h2_a = c(1L, 1L), h2_b = c(2L, 
2L), h2_c = c(3L, 3L), h2_d = c(4L, 4L), h2_e = c(5L, 5L)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")


Thanks, I understand how this works, and the use of function makes this elegant. How would you apply this conditionally while keeping all lines?

@BoTz sorry I missed that bit of the question - only looked at the code. I have edited.

Add subset of columns:
# using Ronak's example data
df[, 2:3] + df[, 4:5]
#   V_a V_b
# 1  27  47
# 2  29  49
# 3  31  51
# 4  33  53
# 5  35  55

#pretty output:
cbind(df[, 1, drop = FALSE],
      df[, 2:3] + df[, 4:5],
      df[, 4:5])
#   cond V_a V_b h2_a h2_b
# 1    1  27  47   26   36
# 2    1  29  49   27   37
# 3    0  31  51   28   38
# 4    1  33  53   29   39
# 5    0  35  55   30   40

